# Put a column image inside the gridview

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

Is there a way put an Icon in the colum header instead of text value in the gridview.I am doing this indirect way like this

```
  <ext:Column ID="Column6" runat="server" Text="TS" Flex="1" Align="Center" DataIndex="SId">
                            <HeaderItems>
                                <ext:Button Dock="Top" ID="Button6" runat="server" IconAlign="Right" IconCls="flagTs" Scale="Large" Flex="1"></ext:Button>
                            </HeaderItems>
                        </ext:Column>
```

I am using a button which get the style outside in that way I put this image.But It really looks ugly
Is there any way  to do that directly and without the messing the  looking of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note the HtmlEncode=false:

```
<asp:BoundField HtmlEncode="false" 
 HeaderText='<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8c9778a09696aac804ed44f4c8033458?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />Filter' />
```

It will render an image on the header and the word Filter next to it.

Comment: first when I saw your answer,I was doubt if It worked .but It works fine.I use it like putting image inside the Text property as u did,I didnt need to use the  HtmlEncode=false: ,as I use ext.net.Thank u so much.

Comment: Great that you got solution. :)